# Disappear div after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html

php file:

```
header('Location: edit.php');
    $_SESSION['ok'] = '<span style="color:green">Dane zostały zaktualizowane!</span>';
```

html file:

```
<div class="editmessage">
<h3 id="message"><?php if(isset($_SESSION['ok'])) echo $_SESSION['ok']; ?></h3>
</div>
```

I want to disappear message after 5 seconds. I found javascript code:

```
var message = document.getElementById('message');
message.onclick = setTimeout(function() {
  message.style.display = 'none';
}, 3000);
```

and it works but after refresh page, again we can see message, that disappears after 5 sec. I want to show message once, not all the time. Maybe you have better idea.

Comment: That's because you didn't remove the `ok` key from your session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add at the bottom of script to unset a session.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['ok'])) {
    unset ($_SESSION['ok']);
}
```

Comment: No, this is PHP code, not JS. The structure should be: `<?php ... $_SESSION['ok'] = '...'; ... //other PHP code; //call template here; if (isset($_SESSION['ok'])) unset($_SESSION['ok']); #end of script here ?>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = document.getElementById('message'); 
message.onclick = setTimeout(function() { 
message.style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['ok'])) { 
session_unset($_SESSION['ok']);
}
?>
 }, 3000);
```

hope can u help this one logic

Comment: It won't work in external JS file (without additional server settings). `session_unset` isn't the function you're looking for (and has no params), in 99.9% you need to use `unset`.